# C++11 result_of deducing my function type failed

Tags: function, c++11, return, result-of

I was trying a program below:

```
#include<type_traits>
using namespace std;
template <class F, class R = typename result_of<F()>::type>
R call(F& f) { return f(); }
int answer() { return 42; }

int main()
{
    call(answer); 
    return 0;
}
```

"call(answer)" fails to compile

VC says 'R call(F&)' could not deduce template argument for 'R'

GCC says |note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|error: function returning a function

I'm not sure if a "function name" could be used for templates. Where did I get wrong, how to make my call(answer) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use forwarding references in these cases:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>
#include<cassert>

using namespace std;

template <class F, class R = typename result_of<F()>::type>
R call(F&& f) { return std::forward<F>(f)(); }

int answer() { return 42; }

int main()
{
    assert(call(answer) == 42);
    return 0;
}
```

It usually avoids troubles.

That said, why your code doesn't work is nicely explained by @T.C. in his answer.
See also the comments to this question for further details.

Comment: But why I cannot call f as an lvalue? function name is always not an "lvalue"?

Comment: You can call it as an lvalue. In your example, because of how template type deduction works, `F` is a function type, not a reference of it. Using forwarding references, `F` is deduced as a reference to `answer`. Try adding `static_assert(std::is_reference<F>::value, "!");` within `call` in my example and in the @T.C.'s one.

Comment: Another test would be adding `std::function<F> func;` within `call` in both the examples. This should help you to understand what's happening there with type deduction for `F`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `f` as an lvalue, so:

```
template <class F, class R = typename result_of<F&()>::type>
//                                               ^
R call(F& f) { return f(); }
```

Comment: I don't quite get this "result_of<F&()>::type. What does F&() mean here?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could avoid the second template argument and use a combination of `auto` and `decltype()`.

Something like

```
#include<type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <class F>
auto call(F& f) -> decltype( f() )
 { return f(); } 

int answer()
 { return 42; }

int main()
{
    call(answer); 

    return 0;
}
```

If you (when you) can use C++14, you can use simply `auto`

```
template <class F>
auto call(F& f)
 { return f(); }
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: These two versions do different things.

Comment: Why two versions do different things?

Comment: @T.C. - do you mean that `auto` can loose consts and references where `decltype(f())` preserve they? So that should be `decltype(auto)` instead of `auto` in C++14?