# C++11: Why result_of can accept functor type as lvalue_reference, but not function type as lvalue_reference?

Tags: function, c++11, types, reference, result-of

I've got program below:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class F, class R = typename result_of<F()>::type>
R call(F& f) { return f(); }

struct S {
    double operator()(){return 0.0;}
};
int f(){return 1;}
int main()
{
    S obj;
    call(obj);//ok
    call(f);//error!
    return 0;
}
```

It fails to compile in the line of "call(f)".
It's weird that "call(obj)" is OK.

(1) I've a similar post in another thread [C++11 result_of deducing my function type failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088944/c11-result-of-deducing-my-function-type-failed). But it doesn't tell why functor objects are OK while functions are not.

(2) I'm not sure if this is related to "R call(F& f)": a function type cannot declare a l-value?

(3) As long as I know, any token with a name, like variable/function, should be considered a l-value. And in the case of function parameter, compiler should "decay" my function name "f" to a function pointer, right?

(4) This is like decaying an array and pass it to a function----And a function pointer could be an l-value, then what's wrong with "call(F& f)"?

Would you help to give some further explanations on "why" is my case, where did I get wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps for the same reason that you can't say `template <typename> struct F {}; F<int()()>{};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with `call(f)` is that you deduce `F` as a function type, so it doesn't decay to a function pointer. Instead you get a reference to a function. Then the `result_of<F()>` expression is invalid, because `F()` is `int()()` i.e. a function that returns a function, which is not a valid type in C++ (functions can return pointers to functions, or references to functions, but not functions).

It will work if you use `result_of<F&()>` which is more accurate anyway, because that's how you're calling the callable object. Inside `call(F& f)` you do `f()` and in that context `f` is an lvalue, so you should ask what the result of invoking an lvalue `F` with no arguments is, otherwise you could get the wrong answer. Consider:

```
struct S {
  double operator()()& {return 0.0;}
  void operator()()&& { }
};
```

Now `result_of<F()>::type` is `void`, which is not the answer you want.

If you use `result_of<F&()>` then you get the right answer, and it also works when `F` is a function type, so `call(f)` works too.

> (3) As long as I know, any token with a name, like variable/function, should be considered a l-value. And in the case of function parameter, compiler should "decay" my function name "f" to a function pointer, right?

No, see above. Your `call(F&)` function takes its argument by reference, so there is no decay.

> (4) This is like decaying an array and pass it to a function----And a function pointer could be an l-value, then what's wrong with "call(F& f)"?

Arrays don't decay when you pass them by reference either.

If you want the argument to decay then you should write `call(F f)` not `call(F& f)`. But even if you do that you still need to use `result_of` correctly to get the result of `f()` where `f` is an lvalue.